# VBA to Count the Total of Completed on the day and depends on criteria split to three different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to learn myself on VBA
But cant find where are the error from.
I created 3 buttons for user to choose the file path and another button is to open the two files and calculate another workbook which split data into three sheets base on one of the column. And the excel file will show the earliest date to the latest day and the total on the day.
Please see below for the coding I found in Google and change myself. Would like to get some data as screenshot below. But not sure how to add data automatically for the following date.
Much appreciate if anyone can help me on this. Many thanks!

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Sub Button12_Click()

    Dim OpenWB As Variant
    Dim IEMS As Workbook
    Dim ZMMR4072 As String
    Dim SummaryWB As Workbook
    Dim CtrlNoIEMS As String
    Dim RecDate As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CtrlNo4072 As Range
    Dim BaseLocation As String
    Dim ItemsType As Range
 
        Set IEMS = Workbooks("Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox1.Value
        If IEMS Is Nothing Then 'Not open
            Application.Workbooks.Open (IEMS)
        End If       
RecDate 
=Workbooks(IEMS) . Range("B" & Rows . Count) . End(xlUp) Row

      For i = 2 To RecDate
         With Range("B" & i)
          .Value = DateValue(.Value)
          .NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
         End With
      Next i

        BaseLocation = Workbooks(IEMS).Range("D:D")
        ItemsType = Workbooks(IEMS).Range("E:E")
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ZMMR4072 = Workbooks("Summary.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").TextBox2.Value
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=ZMMR4072
        Workbooks(ZMMR4072).ThisWorksheets.Activate
        Set CtrlNo4072 = Intersect(Range("DV").EntireColumn, ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
            CtrlNo4072.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW(" & CtrlNo4072.Address & "),IF(" & CtrlNo4072.Address & "<>"""",TRIM(" & CtrlNo4072.Address & "),""""))")
               
    Dim rngToSearch As Range
    Dim strToSearch As String
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim TotalResult As Object
    Dim RemainingResult As Object
    Dim MinDate As Date
    Dim MaxDate As Date
    Dim r As Long
    Dim Seletar As Worksheet
    Dim Changi As Worksheet
    Dim PLA As Worksheet
        'BaseLocation = Workbooks(IEMS).ThisWorksheets.Range("D:D")
        Set SummaryWB = Workbooks.Add
        SummaryWB.Activate
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Seletar"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Total"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Completed"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 4).Value = "% Remaining"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Days Aging"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(2, 1).Value = Workbooks(IEMS).WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(RecDate))
         MinDate = Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(2, 1).Value
         MaxDate = Workbooks(IEMS).WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(RecDate))
            For r = MinDate To MaxDate
                With Range(MinDate & r)
                    r = r + 1
                End With
            Next r
        strToSearch = Workbooks(IEMS).ThisWorksheets.Range("C:C")
        Set rngToSearch = Workbooks(ZMMR4072).ThisWorksheets.Range(CtrlNo4072)
        Set TotalResult = Sheets("Seletar").Range("B2")
        TotalResult = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((RecDate = "A2") * (BaseLocation = "SAB"))
        Set rngResult = Sheets("Seletar").Range("C2")
        rngResult = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((RecDate = "A2") * (BaseLocation = "SAB") * (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngToSearch, strToSearch)))
        Set RemainingResult = Sheets("Seletar").Range("D2")
        RemainingResult = TotalResult - rngResult
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Changi"
        Changi.Activate
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "Seletar"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Total"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Completed"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 4).Value = "% Remaining"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Days Aging"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(2, 1).Value = Workbooks(IEMS).WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(RecDate))
        MinDate = Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Seletar").Cells(2, 1).Value
        MaxDate = Workbooks(IEMS).WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(RecDate))
            For r = MinDate To MaxDate
                With Range(MinDate & r)
                    r = r + 1
                End With
            Next r
        strToSearch = Workbooks(IEMS).ThisWorksheets.Range("C:C")
        Set rngToSearch = Workbooks(ZMMR4072).ThisWorksheets.Range(CtrlNo4072)
        Set TotalResult = Sheets("CHANGI").Range("B2")
        TotalResult = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((RecDate = "A2") * (BaseLocation = "CHG"))
        Set rngResult = Sheets("CHANGI").Range("C2")
        rngResult = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((RecDate = "A2") * (BaseLocation = "CHG") * (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngToSearch, strToSearch)))
        Set RemainingResult = Sheets("CHANGI").Range("D2")
        RemainingResult = TotalResult - rngResult
        
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = PLA
        PLA.Activate
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("Sheet1").Name = "PLA"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("PLA").Cells(1, 1).Value = "Date"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("PLA").Cells(1, 2).Value = "Total"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("PLA").Cells(1, 3).Value = "Completed"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("PLA").Cells(1, 4).Value = "% Remaining"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("PLA").Cells(1, 5).Value = "Days Aging"
        Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("PLA").Cells(2, 1).Value = Workbooks(IEMS).WorksheetFunction.Min(Range(RecDate))
         MinDate = Workbooks(SummaryWB).Worksheets("PLA").Cells(2, 1).Value
         MaxDate = Workbooks(IEMS).WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(RecDate))
            For r = MinDate To MaxDate
                With Range(MinDate & r)
                    r = r + 1
                End With
            Next r
        strToSearch = Workbooks(IEMS).ThisWorksheets.Range("C:C")
        Set rngToSearch = Workbooks(ZMMR4072).ThisWorksheets.Range(CtrlNo4072)
        Set TotalResult = Sheets("Seletar").Range("B2")
        TotalResult = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((RecDate = "A2") * (BaseLocation = "CHG"))
        Set rngResult = Sheets("Seletar").Range("C2")
        rngResult = WorksheetFunction.SumProduct((RecDate = "A2") * (BaseLocation = "CHG") * (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngToSearch, strToSearch)))
        Set RemainingResult = Sheets("CHANGI").Range("D2")
        RemainingResult = TotalResult - rngResult
       
        Workbooks(IEMS).Close SaveChanges:=False
        Workbooks(ZMMR4072).Close SaveChanges:=False
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you identify the error code generated?  Perhaps provide a screenshot?